# regular expression matching with awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm messing around a little with awk and I am still kind of new to bash/awk so bear with me

when I do this to look for all processes running as root

```
ps aux | awk '$0 ~ /.*root*./ {print $0, $11}'
```

it prints out everything as I expect, but it also prints out a line at the bottom that includes MY username (which isn't root) and the process awk.  Why is that? What can I do about it?

Note:  I'm not really interested in alternate solutions to print out all the processes that have root.  I can already do that.  I want to understand what is going on here and how I can use this.

Answer (score 2):

The way to avoid the awk process from being printed is this:

```
ps aux | awk '/[r]oot/ {print $0,$11}'
```

That hack works like this:  awk will be searching for the sequence of characters 'r' 'o' 'o' 't'. The actual awk process is not matched because the ps output contains the sequence of characters '[' 'r' ']' 'o' 'o' 't'.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a couple of issues:  One is that you have *. instead of .* after "root".  The other is that you are searching the whole line and not just the column that contains the username.

$0 represents the entire line.  $1 represents the first column.

Something closer to what you want would be

```
ps aux | awk '$1 ~ /.*root.*/ {print $0, $11}'
```

but you could also just do

```
ps aux | awk '$1=="root" {print $0, $11}'
```

Comment: very interesting.  I understand now.  Why is it searching the whole line.  Is there a way to only search a column?

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

```
ps aux | awk '$0 ~ /^root/ {print $0, $11}'
```

the reason that you have the "last line" is your regex was .*root.*. and your ps|awk line has the same string.  so it is selected.

maybe you can with grep -v "awk" to filter your awk line out.

Comment: Yes! exactly!  Does this make it only search a column?

Comment: no, ^root match the line begins with "root". if you want to search certain column with some value, using awk with $n=xxx or $n~/exp/. n here is the column index.

Answer (score 1):

To exactly match the first field you write

```
ps aux | awk '$1 == "root"' { print $0, $11 }'
```

you can also ask `ps` to filter for you

```
ps -Uroot | awk ' { print $5 } '
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match only process owned by *root* (i.e. records beginning with the string *root*):

```
ps aux | awk '/^root/ { print $0, $11 }'
```

Note that `/regex/` and `$0 ~ /regex/` are equivalent.